# How to paste vector into empty cells of a dataframe column that are not NA in R?

Tags: r

I have a vector of data that looks like this:

```
data_vector <– c("dgh4s", "suc8ec", "sc8cjsn")
```

I want to paste the values of the vector in order into a column of a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df$vector2 <– c("", NA, "", "", NA)
```

So my desired output is:

```
df$vector2 <– c("dgh4s", NA, "suc8ec", "sc8cjsn", NA)
```

I've searched stackoverflow but I can't quite figure out how to do this? Any ideas?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this type, we can use `str_c` instead of `paste` as `str_c` returns `NA` wherever there is an `NA`

```
library(stringr)
str_c(data_vector, df$vector2)
```